# Android sqlite asset helper jar not working with zip.file

Tags: android, sqlite, zip

I am using Android Studio
It works fine when I was using the actual SQLite file (my file name is crud.sqlite).

But when I try to use zip file(crud.zip) instead of crud.sqlite.
the app crash and log say something like unable to find the database file or something like that. I wish I can show you but somehow my debug is not working anymore.....

I hope you guys can help me out.
 - The crud.zip is in the src/main/asset/databases folder. 
 - I think the problem is in my DBHelper class.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crud.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename has to be `crud.sqlite.zip`, not `crud.zip`. This is covered in [the documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#usage).

Comment: Thank you so much! I see it now.
 •ZIP:  assets/databases/northwind.db.zip  
 I should really pay attention on that.